# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p'

Tags: php

im having a error in my code but cant fix the problem, is keeps giving me this error "Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p'". Above i leave my code:

```
$q = "analista/programador";

if (preg_match("/$q/", $i['value'])) { 
        $urlLink = str_replace(" ","+",$i['value']);

        echo "<li><a href='jobs.php?w=".$urlLink."'>".$i['value']."</a></li>"; 
        $count++; 
        if($count >= 6){ 
            break; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Escape the `/` delimiter. Or see `preg_quote()`.

Comment: Above my code or below my code?